# return attributes from all objects of a class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby(and programming in general), but I thought there was a way to call the attributes of all of a classes objects?

```
    class Player
      attr_reader :number

      def initialize(name, number)
        @name = name
        @number = number
      end

      def self.all_numbers
        [] << Player.each {|person| person.number}
      end
    end

   guy1 = Player.new('Bill', 23)
   guy2 = Player.new('jeff', 18)
```

I would like to just access the numbers for all objects by calling the class..

```
   Player.all_numbers
```

hoping to return..

```
    [23, 18]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have right now is that `Player` is your custom class. It does not respond to a class method `each`. Another issue is that the `Player` class has no knowledge of the instances created outside of it.

There's many ways to go about this. The way I would do this is to implement another class called Team like this

```
class Team
  def initialize(*players)
    @players = players
  end

  def player_numbers
    @players.map { |player| player.number }
  end
end

class Player
  attr_reader :number

  def initialize(name, number)
    @name = name
    @number = number
  end
end

guy1 = Player.new('Bill', 23)
guy2 = Player.new('jeff', 18)

team = Team.new(guy1, guy2)
team.player_numbers
#=> [23, 18]
```

Answer (score 2):

Write as below with the help of [`ObjectSpace#each_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) :

> Calls the block once for each living, nonimmediate object in this Ruby process. If module is specified, calls the block for only those classes or modules that match (or are a subclass of) module. Returns the number of objects found. Immediate objects (Fixnums, Symbols true, false, and nil) are never returned.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

```
class Player
  attr_reader :number

  def initialize(name, number)
    @name = name
    @number = number
  end

  def self.all_numbers
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).map(&:number)
  end
end

guy1 = Player.new('Bill', 23) 
guy2 = Player.new('jeff', 18) 


Player.all_numbers
# => [18, 23]
```

## Another approach

```
class Player
  attr_reader :number
  @class_obj = []

  def initialize(name, number)
    @name = name
    @number = number
    self.class.add_object(self)
  end

  def self.add_object(ob)
    @class_obj << ob
  end

  def self.all_numbers
    @class_obj.map(&:number)
  end
end

guy1 = Player.new('Bill', 23)  
guy2 = Player.new('jeff', 18)  

Player.all_numbers
# => [23, 18]
```

Comment: This is a way to do this. However, since the @Carpk is just learning programming/ruby, I wouldn't do it this way since a `Player` class should not know the numbers of all its instances. Neat solution though.

Comment: @LeoCorrea Keeping your words in mind, I have shown another approach.. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Arup, I prefer the elegance of the first approach, but the security of the second.  Somewhere I read that `ObjectSpace#each_object` can pick up objects that are abandoned but not yet garbage-collected.  It would be a good idea to check the validity of that before using it in this context.  Anybody know about that?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your comment. [follow here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4419453#1131229) to get your answer. You put a valid question. Thanks for teaching.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Class Variable

Using a Team to hold references to complete Player objects is probably more desirable from a design perspective, but you can do what you want with a simple class variable. For example:

```
class Player
  attr_reader :number

  @@numbers = []

  def initialize(name, number)
    @name = name
    @number = number
    @@numbers << @number
  end

  def self.all_numbers
    @@numbers
  end
end

guy1 = Player.new 'Bill', 23
guy2 = Player.new 'jeff', 18

Player.all_numbers 
#=> [23, 18]
```

For this simple use case, that's probably sufficient. However, if you find yourself trying to stuff entire Player objects into a Player class variable then you will definitely want to find a better noun (e.g. Team or Players) to hold your collection.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply override `new` and save the instances in a class variable:

```
    class Player
      attr_reader :number

      def initialize(name, number)
        @name = name
        @number = number
      end

      def self.new(*args)
        (@@players ||= []) << super
        @@players.last
      end

      def self.all_numbers
        @@players.reduce([]) {|arr, player| arr << player.number}
      end
    end

   Player.new('Bill', 23)
   Player.new('jeff', 18)
   p Player.all_numbers # => [23, 18]
```

Carpk, I should explain a few things:

- Normally, `Player.new('Bill', 23)` would send the method `Class#new` to class `Player`, together with the two arguments.  By defining `self.new` here, I am overriding `Class#new`.  `self.new` invokes `super`, which invokes `Class#new` with `self.new`'s arguments (there is no need to explicitly pass the arguments, unless you only want to pass some or none). `Class#new` returns the new class instance to `self.new`, which returns it as well, but first saves it in the array `@@player`.
- `(@@players ||= [])` is a typical Ruby trick.  This has the effect of setting `@@players` equal to an empty array if it has not yet been defined (is nil), and leaves it unchanged if it already an array (empty or not).  This is because `@@players ||= []` is the same as `@@players = @@players || []`.  If `@@players => nil`, this becomes `@@players = []`; else,  `@@players` remains unchanged (`[]` is never evaluated). Cute, eh?
- `@@players.last` returns the class instance that was just returned by `Class#new` and added to the end of `@@players`.
- `@@players.reduce([]) {|arr, player| arr << player.number}` creates and returns an array `arr` of class instances, which in turn `self.all_numbers` returns.  `reduce`'s argument is the initial value of the accumulator, here an empty array named `arr` within the block.  Note `reduce` and `inject` are synonyms.

---

Carpk, don't read any further; it will just be confusing.

I lied. I actually wouldn't do it that way. I suggested using a class variable and class methods because Carpk is new to Ruby and probably not into metaprogramming in a big way.  What I'd actually do is define a class instance variable `@players` and make `new` and `all_numbers` singleton methods of the class `Player`.  That way, instances of the class `Player` would not have easy access to that variable or those two methods.  To do this, simply replace the above definitions of `self.new` and `self.all_numbers` with the following:

```
class << self
  def new(*args)
    (@players ||= []) << super
    @players.last
  end

  def all_numbers
    @players.reduce([]) {|arr, player| arr << player.number}
  end
end
```

Carpk, I warned you.